# Saving a Set into Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, set

Hi I'm currently trying to set up core data in my project after previously using NSCoding.

I have the problem that I can't save a Set into Core Data. I've looked for days on ways to convert it to Binary data in Swift and saving that but I can't seem to find anything.

The set contains elements of a custom object I made.

PS: If possible, also, how would a generic be saved into Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift sets are bridged to the foundation class `NSSet`, and `NSSet` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol. That means you can save a set as an attribute of a managed object if you

1. Treat the set as an `NSSet` (if it's not one already, use `mySet as NSSet`)
2. Adopt `NSCoding` on your custom objects in the set
3. Make the Core Data attribute type "transformable"

If you do all that, Core Data will automatically invoke `NSCoding` methods on the set, which will in turn invoke the same methods on your custom objects. You'll just assign the set to the attribute, and Core Data will do the rest.